# onMouseOver event when dragging a div

Tags: javascript, css, html, reactjs, draggable

I'm using react-draggable to drag a div to another location on the table. The issue is I need to have the underlying `<td>`'s fire an `onMouseOver` event while I'm dragging the div above them. But since my mouse is over the draggable div, the mouse event does not fire on the underlying `<td>`'s.

I've tried to use `pointer-events: none;` but that results in the draggable not being draggable.

```
<td className={cls} onClick={this.handleCancelOpenOrders} onMouseOver={this.handleMouseOver}>
    <Draggable axis="y" position={{ x: 0, y: 0 }} onDrag={this.handleDrag} onStart={this.handleDragStart} onStop={this.handleDragStop}>
        <div className={styles[this.props.type]}>
            <span className={styles.currentOrderText}>
                  {orderQuantity}
            </span>
        </div>
    </Draggable>
</td>
```

Comment: Can you post some of your code to help us?

Comment: @MatheusCuba updated with code snippet.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix this by creating an observable isDraggable and when it is true setting the pointer-events: none; on the div being dragged.